Assessing the Implementation and Performance of a New Biomarker in Cancer Surveillance
In a surveillance program designed to detect a specific type of cancer in a high-risk population, both biomarker A and ultrasound (US) are used semi-annually. If either A or US returns a positive result, a confirmatory test is administered.
A new study aims to evaluate another biomarker, G, to be used alongside US. Since we cannot alter the standard pathway until G's performance is validated, all participants in the study will receive tests for A, G, and US. If any of these tests return a positive result, the patient will undergo a confirmatory test. Due to the high cost of the confirmatory test, it will not be administered to those who test negative on all index tests (partial verification).
Biomarker G incorporates A, along with additional components, to detect cancer. Thus, G and A are correlated, though the degree of correlation is unknown. A study has shown that G has higher sensitivity than A alone. Based on figures from a meta analysis, it appears G also has higher sensitivity and specificity than the combination of A and US. However, no study has directly compared G/G+US with A/A+US.
This comparison is essential for evaluating both test accuracy and cost-effectiveness. It seems intuitive that G+US would have better sensitivity than A+US, although it might have lower specificity given A’s high specificity. However, this hypothesis needs to be tested and sample size justification is needed for grant application.
Questions:
Is it appropriate to reduce this study to comparing G versus A?
What is the best method to demonstrate the superiority of G+US over A+US? Should we focus on comparing the sensitivity of the two combinations? Or is there a method to show the added value of G in detection accuracy, considering G includes A?
What sample size is required for this comparison?
If comparing sensitivities is appropriate, what is the best sample size calculation method?
I found a paper by Wu (2024) titled "Sample size calculation for comparing two screening tests when the gold standard is missing at random" (doi: 10.1002/sim.10109), which proposes simplified sample size calculations for comparing paired diagnostic tests with partial verification, including scenarios where those with negative index tests do not receive verification. All methods consider the correlation between the two index tests. However, one method is deemed unsuitable when the correlation between index tests is high, which might be relevant in our case. Here is the link to the relevant study: (https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0167947308003782). And I'm not sure if this applies to the other methods as well.
Any insights on these questions would be greatly appreciated!

This question having remained unanswered for a while, I will share some thoughts, and offer some suggestions.

It is key to note that, even with partial verification, you can still estimate the sensitivity/specificity of the various tests (A, G, US) and of any combination of them (A+US, G+US, A+G+US, etc...). For example, whenever you get a A+ result (positive for biomarker A), you will always have a confirmatory test C (which is assumed to be the "ground truth"). If you get a C+, you have a TP (true positive), C- is a FP. Now if you had a A- result, you will not always run a C test, but you will for some (the ones where you had A-, but either G or US was positive). So you can also estimate the TN's and FN's, but on a smaller sample than all A-'s. Does that bias your A-'s sample? Possibly; but if you do not make the assumption that it does not, then you can not even estimate the specificity, and you can only talk about sensitivity. Which may, or not, be enough for your purpose. (I know I would look at both, and test both, but I would make a mention that the specificity values may be biased because we did not confirm all the negative samples). That would "tend" to make the specificity worse (the ones included in the analysis are "borderline" negatives; they are positive for 1 or more test, and negative for 1 or more. They may -or not- be different than negatives for all 3 A, G and US).
One idea to deal with the partial verification, is to perform a full verification on a (small) subset (to save \$) of the fully negative tests (negative for A, G & US). If the specificity measured for a given test (or combo of tests) (e.g. G alone) is "similar" for the "all 3 negative tests" group to the "at least 1 other test was not negative" group, then you can use that argument to state that the assumption is plausible. Otherwise, your estimate of specificity -and hence NPV and PPV- will be flawed. And if the TNR and FNR are similar, then I would add these negative data to the confusion matrix (because they seem identically distributed to the other negative data, for the test or combo under study).
If your original sample was truly randomly sampled from the likely target population, then you can also estimate the PPV and NPV. If you "spiked" your sample with e.g. positive subjects (often done for diagnostic tests, because prevalece is usually quite low), then you can use an estimate of the population prevalence, and estimate PPV and NPV "indirectly".
Not only would I estimate Sessitivity, Specificity, PPV and NPV, but I would also get CI's around all these. And again, I would do it for A, G, and US separately, and for the combinations of interest (e.g. A+US -current standard or care-, G+US -possible alternative-, etc...) (note that you can not estimate specificity -and hence NPV, PPV- for A+G+US because none of the negatives will have a confirmation test; you do not know TN and FN). One could argue that we are performing "multiple comparisons"; you can adjust your $\alpha$ accordingly, so that your results may be considered definitive (but that will increase your sample size!), or not (stating that this was an exploratory study, to look at possible interesting differences, to be followed by a confirmatory study, focusing just on 1 or 2 such differences, e.g. sensitivity/specificity between A+US and G+US). I would not count comparisons of PPV or NPV as additional comparisons, because they are directly derived from sensitivity/soecificity and prevalence (the later being a population constant parameter).
The required sample size now depends on basically the width of the CI's you think are required for you to see a clinically significant effect (is $\pm1%$ sensitivity difference clinically significant; probably not. Is $\pm5%$ clinically significant? Probably?). The CI's for sensitivity/specificity are basically binomial CI's. So any binomial sample size calculator will allow you to estimate the required sample size. You can also find good references here (CV), and here, and online calculators here and here.
One issue you will have with sample size is that, while you can determine how many samples you need to properly assess sensitivity/specificity, you will not know how many total subjects to enroll in the study before hand. This is because you do not know a-priori how many will be + or -, nor for which test(s) they will be + or -, etc. So you can establish stopping points (for each of the test and combos of interest), but you can not pre-define the total enrollment.
Therefore, I would not "reduce" the study to just comparing A to G (no reason to). You could "reduce" it to comparing A+US to G+US (after all, that seems to be the final objective; replacing A by G, but still in conjunction with US); but I would look at all the other "interesting" comparisons, at least for my own benefit (I may not publish them, unless they show a clinically (or economically) significant result; e.g. how about G alone against A+US). "Reduction" saves you from the issue of multiple comparisons; your choice.
And the method to do the comparisons is just the good old confusion matrix, with CI's.


Thank you very much for sharing your detailed thoughts and suggestions. The sample size calculations using the sources you provided align with what I have done, which is reassuring (phew!). You are right that we cannot determine the actual number of patients to recruit. Hence, we only calculated the number of actual positives we need to assess sensitivities, and based on figures from an audit, the period of surveillance to detect that many cancers was used instead of the number of participants.

Since the goal is to improve early-stage cancer detection, the primary objective is sensitivity. However, estimating specificity is also crucial for the health economic assessment. What sample size should be taken from all negatives for the confirmatory test? The confirmatory test is quite expensive and time-consuming.
Could you also explain how point 2 in your answer works?

You can use the same sample size calculation software/site. Here, since you are doing this just to evaluate specificity, you can assume a very low prevalence (even 0), and use the same binomial test sample size calculators. Depending on the estimated specificity, and the margin of errors, that could go from ~50 to ~150. If you do not do this, the specificity will be assessed on a "biased" sample (at least positive for 1 assay), and may not be trustworthy (if anything, it may be lower than actual).
